# How to write complex type in json format using OCI CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I try to update a compute instance in oci cli but the command below:

```
oci compute instance update --instance-id=ocid1.instance.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaa... --defined-tags '{"data":{"launch-options":{"firmware":"UEFI_64"}}}'
```

results this error:

> ServiceError: {
>       "code": "Bad Request",
>       "message": "Tag values must be strings",
>       "opc-request-id": "7B645B7F3D3F4047BE04E39DD6F4CCCA/8904CFD298C5E9F34AF032AF079EB84A/F627F1D27D0DF095A32C89C4701554F1",
>       "status": 400 }

How should I format my tag value correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I did some further tests based on the input by @user3291073 I found the right solution: 
First you have to create a tag namespace and tag key definition, then you have to refer to the existing tag namespace and tag key definition in the cli --defined-tags option. So for my previous example this will work with an existing launch-options tag namespace with a firmware tag key definition:

```
oci compute instance update --instance-id=ocid1.instance.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaa... --defined-tags '{"launch-options":{"firmware":"UEFI_64"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently strings are the only supported data type for Defined Tags:
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Identity/Concepts/taggingoverview.htm#Defined

So you can only do something like:
`--defined-tags '{"tag_name_1": "tag_value_1"}'`

Comment: You can actually use complex types, but the namespace have to be created in advance. Without having the referenced namespace created before, you will get another error message, which is "InvalidParameter". So at the end it should look like this: `--defined-tags '{"tag_namespace_1":{"tag_name_1":"tag_value_1"}}'`